# How to make JOOQ generate both enum types and custom types?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jooq

I am using JOOQ-codegen 3.6.1.

When I generate my code it usually generates all Enum types fine. However JOOQ stops generating Enums when I add a custom type like so:

```
  <customTypes>
    <customType>
      <name>LocalDateTime</name>
      <type>java.time.LocalDateTime</type>
      <converter>com.example.util.LocalDateTimeConverter</converter>
    </customType>
  </customTypes>
  <forcedTypes>
    <forcedType>
      <name>LocalDateTime</name>
      <types>TIMESTAMP</types>
    </forcedType>
  </forcedTypes>
```

The LocalDateTime data type is generated just fine in this case. I can't seem to find a way to generate both Enums and my custom data type.

It seems like JOOQ does not even detect Enums when there is a custom data type, as I get the log message:

> INFO: Enums fetched            : 0 (0 included, 0 excluded)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is a bug in jOOQ, I reported it here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jooq-user/ENPvgqtVwW0

As a workaround you could avoid using <types> filter and always use <expression> filter to select the columns.